# Close .netslclient data provider within function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Listview that is bound to a function called GetAmountStyles(). When this function is fired it creates 44 sql connections. No matter where I try to close the SQL connection, it won't close. Where and how can I close these connections?

```
 protected string GetAmountStyle()
{
    //Makes SQl connection 
    SqlConnection testDBconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testDBconn"].ConnectionString);
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
   testDBconn.Open();

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand CurrAllsessions = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select UserName from TenHrsLogins union Select UserName from permlogins ", testDBconn);
    SqlDataReader dr = CurrAllsessions.ExecuteReader();
    string Login = Convert.ToString(Eval("Login"));




    while (dr.Read())
    {
        //if (Login.Contains(dr.GetValue(0).ToString()) == true)
        if (Login.Contains(dr.GetValue(0).ToString()) == true)
        {

            dr.Dispose();
            return "background-color: #FFC6C6;";



        }
        else
        {



        }


    }
    dr.Dispose();
    testDBconn.Close();
    return "testDBconn.Close();";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning

```
return "background-color: #FFC6C6;";
```

before you close the connection. As a rule of thumb use using, no need for explicit dispose or close. Like this:

```
using(var testDBconn = new SqlConnection(...)) {
   testDBconn.Open();
   // do whatever you like with connection, it will close automatically
   using(var dr = CurrAllsessions.ExecuteReader()) {
     // do whatever you like with data reader
   }
}
```